# Setting UIDateTime Picker time zone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have rather unusual requirement, but anyway..

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dateDatePicker;
```

When I get reading of dateDatePicker.date it returns NSDate set to current system's time zone. But I want it to be in different specific time zone.

So, pretend right now it's 3:50pm Central Time.
dateDatePicker.date returns 3:50pm CST

I want to have something like this:

```
[dateDatePicker setTimeZone:@"EST"]
NSDate *ESTDate = dateDatePicker.date;
```

... and then I'd like debugger to show "2:50pm CST" - because 3:50pm in EST IS 2:50CST

Comment: In my opinion the date picker should be a strong reference. You may not encounter any issues because it is retained by its superview, but it should also be retained by the owner, which is your view controller, I guess, in case you temporarily remove it form the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

This may be simpler that you think. If your date is 3:50pm CST, and you want it to be 2:50pm CST, just subtract an hour:

```
date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-3600];
```

Of course, the local time zone might not always be CST, so you can get the difference between the two time zones and use that instead of hard coding -3600:

```
NSString *targetTimeZoneName = @"US/Eastern";
NSInteger localOffset = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSInteger targetOffset = [[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:targetTimeZoneName] secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSInteger timeZoneDelta = localOffset - targetOffset;

date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeZoneDelta];
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIDatePicker`'s `timeZone` property is not a string, as you are using it. You have to pass it an `NSTimeZone` object.

Also, `NSDate`s do not have a timezone. Its just a moment in history and its string representation depends on the time zone. Use an `NSDateFormatter` to format the date object for the timezone you want.